# Is it possible to continue a Flash game session on a different computer?

Tags: flash, mardek-3

I am currently playing a flash-game (Mardek RPG chapter 3) and I found it pretty long. I've done quite a lot of progress on a computer that's not mine (it belongs to my relatives), and now I want to continue playing this session on my computer.

I'm playing it off-line, so the saved data is on the computer.

Is it possible to transfer the saved data to my own computer? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 11):

The solution depends on your operating system.  From the Kongregate forums:

> 1. Go to Folder Settings in Windows and turn hidden folders ON.
> 2. Next, go to
>
> C:\Users\YOUR WINDOWS
>   USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\#SharedObjects\SOME
>   RANDOM LETTERS AND NUMBERS\
>
> 3. There should be two folders, one named chat.kongregate.com and one named armorgames.com or a different website you played it on
> 4. Copy the save files/folders from the source computer to the destination computer
> 5. You’re DONE! You can now pick up where you left off, and hopefully make progress towards the new badges (which WILL appear… eventually)

The folder locations for various OS's are as follows:

On Microsoft Windows NT 5.x and 6.x, they are stored in:

```
 %APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\
 %APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\
```

On Mac OS X, they are stored in:

```
~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/
~/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/
```

On Linux or Unix, they are stored in:

```
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/
```

For Linux and Unix systems, if the open-source Gnash plugin is being used instead of the official Adobe Flash, they will instead be found at:

```
~/.gnash/SharedObjects/
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object#File_locations

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your relative's computer is running windows, flash local storage is usually found in a location such as:

`C:/Users/[USERNAME]/AppData/Roaming/Macromedia/Flash Player/SharedObjects/[RANDOM LETTERS]/[NAME OF WEBSITE]`

I'd suggest checking there for any files, I can't remember if `Roaming` is a hidden folder by default, so you might need to show hidden folders. Copy the related files and place them on your computer. This *should* let you continue your game.